# background image not showing for edit text from @drawable

Tags: c#, android, xml, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have created android app using xamarin native and put some pics in res/drawable but when I want to use that images in xml they don't show up neither in designer view nor in intellisense.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="156dp"
        **android:background="@drawable/emailbg"**
        android:hint="Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:paddingStart="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:textColorHint="#a3a3a3"
        android:id="@+id/pass_et"
/>
```

Comment: Xml is a text file and does not display images.  An xml only can have links to images.

Comment: Can you confirm the images are in .png format? also check if that images are under "drawable" directory not "drawable v24".

Answer (score 0):

Please mark sure that you are putting the image under `drawable` folder and the `Build Action` is `AndroidResource`.

If the image does not show up, try to close Visual-Studio and open again.

Here is a screenshot I did and it works well on my side. Feel free to ask me any question.

[image]